# what's the easiest idea to print only certain portion of document

Tags: javascript, css, printing

I am trying to print only selected area of document. I tried adding the content of the selected area/div to new window and call window.print, but the problem occured about the css. Since my page has css from multiple files its hard for me to load those css files once more.

So i need to export the selected area/div content with inline styles to new document and print them.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, if your external stylesheets do more harm than good to your print output, you can limit them to screen media with a simple media query: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" media="screen,projection" />`

This way your print stylesheet could start with an unstyled page, not having to reset any previous sheets.

A typical print stylesheet hides ads, resets colors to high-contrast colors and adjusts typography - Take a look at [the print section](https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/css/style.css#L274) of HTML5 Boilerplate.

If by "selected area" you mean the user can decide what needs to be printed, you can easily achieve that by doing something like `.addClass('print');` to the JavaScript handler and then your print CSS could look like the following:

```
* {display: none;}
.print, .print * {display: block;} /* Or inline, depending on the element */
```

If you don't care about IE<9, you can just do this:

```
body :not(.print) {display: none;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the print media type to specify a CSS file that'll only apply to your page when you're printing it. You can hide all the unnecessary elements in the print CSS file.

http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/cssmedia.shtml